# Prevent a Variable from being converted into a Const when freezing a TensorFlow graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to use the freeze_graph.py tool to save a model, but have run into an issue.

There is a variable in my tensorflow graph which I either assign to using tf.assign, or feed before each inference. I need it to remain a variable because tf.assign requires a mutable tensor and you also can't feed to a const, but the freeze_graph script converts all variables into constants.

I've noticed that freeze_graph has whitelist and blacklist parameters, but I can't for the life of me find any documentation on what these are or how to use them. What can I do here?

*edit:*

`single_c` and `single_h` are the variables I'd like to preserve:

```
single_c = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([num_lstm_cells], 0, 1), trainable=True)
expanded_c = tf.reshape(single_c, [1, num_lstm_cells])
batched_c = tf.tile(expanded_c, tiling_shape, name='c')

single_h = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([num_lstm_cells], 0, 1), trainable=True)
expanded_h = tf.reshape(single_h, [1, num_lstm_cells])
batched_h = tf.tile(expanded_h, tiling_shape, name='h')

state = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple(batched_c, batched_h)
```

because I assign them using:

```
restore_c = tf.assign(single_c, c_holder)
restore_h = tf.assign(single_h, h_holder)
```

and I feed `state` using

```
_, er, new = sess.run([train_nn_step, error, new_state], feed_dict={batch_ph: batch_size, prob: training_dropout, state: new})
```

I can't assign or feed if `single_c` and `single_h` become constants

Comment: Can you show us a minimal example? It would be very helpful...Also, if you're using the Estimator API, you can export your model more easily (without using the freeze_graph script)

Comment: I've added an example. No I don't use the estimator API